# Deleted/Can' Find Wallet

Tags: wallet.dat, lost-wallet

I bought and used bitcoins 5-6 years ago through a machine (paid cash) in a bank here in Australia, I had a wallet/dat.file on my Mac Desktop that I think has been deleted well at last I can't find it, I do remember my password for the wallet but am having trouble finding it, any ways to reinstall it ? The Mac still works fine and has never been wiped I just recently pulled it out of storage and i'm sure that there are coins still in my wallet.

Please Help!

Comment: while reading again, are you sure you have the same user ID? You need the same user ID to find the file named wallet.dat, see comment below by MCCCS...

Answer (score 2):

1) Click Finder.

2) Press CMD + SHIFT + G

3) Paste this and press enter:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin
```

Your `wallet.dat` should be there.

Comment: I always forget this shortcut :-) thx for reminding me.

Answer (score 0):

how familiar are you with command line/terminal? 
If so, log off, and re-logon. Open terminal, enter this command:

```
cd
pwd
```

this should show you s.th. like `/Users/<username>`.
Then go to this directory:

```
cd /Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin
```

and see whats in there. The file called wallet.dat is what you are looking for. 
Alternativly you can try to navigate to this location in finder, you would need to hold the ALT key, to get the "Library" folder displayed in the "go to" menu...